# Problem saving multiple JSON records to a file

Tags: php, json, file-io

I made an HTML form that sends the data to JSON, but I experienced a problem with code I took from a tutorial. It makes a new JSON file every time I submit a new form. How to make it so it adds the data to it, not rewrite it?

This is the PHP code I'm using

```php
<?php
    
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
          
        function get_data() {
            $datae = array();
            $datae[] = array(
                'Name' => $_POST['name'],
                'Strategy' => $_POST['strategy'],
                'Teams' => $_POST['team'],
            );
            return json_encode($datae);
        }
          
        $name = "strategies";
        $file_name = $name . '.json';
       
        if(file_put_contents(
            "$file_name", get_data())) {
                echo $file_name .' file created';
            }
        else {
            echo 'There is some error';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Well, create a  HTML form with one of the input boxes as a select dropdown which has the A and B options. When the form is submitted, insert in the DB accordingly.

Comment: ["Strat"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strat) is a commonly used abbreviation in online gaming for the word "strategy".

Comment: @nice_dev Yep, I have this done. Just the part where I need to add the data to JSON is a part that I don't understand. Been googling for a few hours and I am just stuck. 
https://codepen.io/ErkkiTa/pen/rNddJwj This is the current situation.

EDIT: Oh, found one tutorial that explains it quite well. will try this and get back with the results.

Comment: So your question is actually how to append to a file? Actually if it's JSON, to get a single coherent, decodable object in your file, you can't just simply append to the file. You need to pull out the existing object, decode it to a PHP variable (object or array, depending on your data structure), put your new data into that structure, encode it to JSON again and then overwrite the file contents with the new version.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, basically I want to do this: HTML form inputs all go into JSON and whenever I add new ones, it just puts them in the same JSON file that was done earlier. Just so I can add like 50 entries and they are all in the same file.

Comment: Ok well then you need to follow the process I described above.

Comment: Either that, or do what most people would do in this kind of situation and make a simple database to store this information. Text files are not good at the kind of task you're trying to use it for.

Comment: @ADyson Okay will search into the database way then. Thank you for your suggestions